# User vs Mathematica functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, filtering

Is there a way to distinguish between functions defined by the user and Mathematica built-in functions (such as `Sin`, `Power` etc.)?

For example, how can I select symbols and functions in a list such as

```
{a,Sqrt[b²+f[x]²],g[h[y]]}
(*{a,b,f,x,g,h,y}*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly hacked something together. The comment didn't helped much for me since it serves only for a special case while you want a more general functionality.

```
extractSmbFnc[expr_]:=(If[Head[#]=!=Symbol,Head[#],#]&)/@DeleteDuplicates[Cases[{expr},_?(If[Head[#]===Symbol,Context[#],If[MatchQ[Head[#],_Symbol],Context[Evaluate@Head[#]]]]==="Global`"&),Infinity]]
```

This is a simple function which can be called with the expression you want to analyze:

```
testList={a,Sqrt[b^2+f[x]^2],g[h[y]],Pi,Mod[x,2]};
extractSmbFnc[testList]
```

> {a,b,x,f,y,h,g}

Comment: Symbols are not always ``Global` ``, custom packages generate symbols in their context. Also, when working with CellContext set local to Notebook there is no Global context there. I'm not sure what is wrong with discarding ``System` ``.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. As I said, i quickly hacked it together and my first thought laid on Global so i went with it. OP can change it to System if he needs to.